# Dynamically chain methods to javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, firebase

I am using Google's Firestore for searching a database, and the logic is to name your source, then chain where() methods for each variable.
An example of working code is:

```
var ref = firebase.firestore().collection('myCol');
ref.where('myVar1','==',true).where('myVar2','==',5).get()
.then((results) => {...})
```

The problem I'm having is I have no idea how to dynamically attach those where() methods (as the number of them will change with each different search).
I suspect if I knew the name of it I'd be able to find it, but dot functions didn't show up much... How could I do this?

Comment: What are "dot functions"?

Comment: Chaining is often just a case where the method returns itself, or another object.  So just a keep a reference to this.. eg.. `var last = ref.where(..);`, then `last = last.where(..)`  etc.

Comment: Please don't use the question to provide an answer to it. Instead write your answer below. You can accept it in 2 days as well. If you are looking for an answer, the question is definitely not the first place you are looking for it ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From @Keith's reply below, I got it working using:

```
var vars = ['myVar1', 'myVar2', 'myVar3'];
var ref = firebase.firestore().collection('myCol');

vars.forEach(v => { ref = ref.where(v, '==', true) });

ref.get()
  .then(results => { ... })
  .catch(err => { ... })
```

Comment: `var ref = vars.reduce((ref, v) => ref.where(v, '==', true), firebase.firestore().collection('myCol'));` also works